# MYSQL Update a huge SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

In my system I want to get attendance data of employee from the DB, so I wrote a huge SQL query, and it gives me relevant details. But now I need an updated version of particular results. So I don’t know how to put this query within the update statement.

```
select * from(
select concat('pre:', date) as date,concat('pre:',employee_no) as employee_no,concat('pre:',name_with_initials) as name,concat('pre:',sign_in_at) as sign_in_at,concat('pre:',sign_out_at) as sign_out_at,emp from(               SELECT date, present.employee_no,employee_details.name_with_initials,present.sign_in_at, present.sign_out_at,employee_details.employee_no as emp  from ( 
                         SELECT employee_no,date,sign_in_at,sign_out_at FROM complete_shifts WHERE date = '2013-06-17'  UNION ALL
                         SELECT employee_no,date,sign_in_at,'00:00:00 ' AS sign_out_at  FROM incomplete_shifts WHERE date = '2013-06-17'  UNION ALL
                         SELECT employee_no,date,sign_in_at,'00:00:00 ' AS sign_out_at FROM incomplete_shift_records WHERE date = '2013-06-17' 
            )as present inner join employee_details on present.employee_no = employee_details.employee_no
) as final_present

   union all

select concat('ab:',date)as date,concat('ab:',employee_no)as employee_no,concat('ab:',name_with_initials)as name,concat('ab:',sign_in_at)as sign_in_at,concat('ab:',sign_out_at)as sign_out_at, emp from(
         select '2013-06-17' AS date,absent.employee_no,employee_details.name_with_initials,'00:00:00'as sign_in_at , '00:00:00' as sign_out_at,employee_details.employee_no as emp  from (                     
                   select * from ( SELECT employee_details.employee_no  FROM employee_details left outer join resigned_emps on 
                             employee_details.employee_no = resigned_emps.employee_no where resigned_emps.date is null or resigned_emps.date>'2013-06-17'
                  ) as available_emps  left outer join (
                  select employee_no from complete_shifts where date  = '2013-06-17'  union 
                  select employee_no from incomplete_shifts where date = '2013-06-17' union 
                  select employee_no from incomplete_shift_records where date  = '2013-06-17'
                  ) as present  on available_emps.employee_no = present.employee_no where present.employee_no is null 
        ) as absent inner join employee_details on absent.employee_no =  employee_details.employee_no
) as final_absent

)as final left outer join(  SELECT  leave.employee_no as lv_emp
                                                                                            FROM leave_dates  inner join leave on leave_dates.leave_id = leave.leave_id   where leave_dates.date  = '2013-06-17')as leave_emps 
on final.emp = leave_emps.lv_emp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such a large query, you should just put the results in a temporary table and update from that.

```
create temporary table toupdate as
    <your query goes here>;
```

Now you can investigate the data that will be updated, to be sure that it really is ok.

Next you can do the update as a join:

```
update table_to_update t join
       toupdate
       on t.key = toupdate.key
    set t.col = toupdate.col
```

Because you don't give the column or table details, this is just the structure of such a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "select *", use the appropriate unique field to fetch the records to update, ex EmpID. Finally use this result as inner query result to update query.

Example

Update ... set ... where empid in (your select query goes here)